# QTcpSocket client auto reconnect

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I'm trying to write a piece of code that periodically tries to connect to the server using QTcpSocket until the server is up and ready. The client should also automatically and periodically try reconnecting when the server is down until it is up again or user manually closes the program.

What I have done is subscribing to the connected and error signals of QTcpSocket. When I catch the error signal, I basically call connectToHost method again.

My code periodically tries to connect to the host until the server is ready (this part works fine). However, the problem is when the server is down it can never reconnect. When the connection is down I get RemoteHostClosedError as expected. But, after calling the connectToHost method again inside the same method (where I catch RemoteHostClosedError) I got nothing. Even the error signal is not emitted by the QTcpSocket object.

I gave my code below.

```
TcpServerConnector::TcpServerConnector( SocketSettings socketSettings, QObject* parent)
: QObject(parent), socket(new QTcpSocket())
{
    this->connect(this->socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connectionSuccess_Handler()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    this->connect(this->socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(connectionError_Handler(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), Qt::DirectConnection);
}


void TcpServerConnector::connectionError_Handler( QAbstractSocket::SocketError error )
{
    switch (error)
    {
    case QAbstractSocket::AddressInUseError:
        this->logger.log(LogLevel::ERR, "SOCKET ERROR: Address is already in use");
        break;
    case QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError:
        this->logger.log(LogLevel::ERR, "SOCKET ERROR: Connection refused");
        break;
    case QAbstractSocket::HostNotFoundError:
        this->logger.log(LogLevel::ERR, "SOCKET ERROR: Host not found");
        break;
    case QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError:
        this->logger.log(LogLevel::ERR, "SOCKET ERROR: Remote host closed");            
        break;  
    }


    this->socket->abort();
    this->socket->close();
    this->logger.log(LogLevel::DEBUG, "Reconnecting...");
    SystemUtil::sleepCurrentThread(1000);
    this->socket->connectToHost(ip_address, port);
}
```

}

I check the state of the QTcpSocket before and after calling the connectToHost method (the last line I gave here). Before calling connectToHost the state is UnconnectedState and after calling connectToHost its state becomes Connecting. Nothing unexpected. However, neither it can connect to the server, nor emit an error signal.

Any idea?

Note: The connectToHost metod of QTcpSocket is called internally for the first time.

Comment: Do not reconnect from error handler slot. "When this signal is emitted, the socket may not be ready for a reconnect attempt." [qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the ones who may come across with a similar situation, the reset method of the QTcpSocket solved the problem.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct, when you solve problems. In this way someone searching for this will quickly find the solution.

Comment: would you please post your solution...Tnx ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am was across this situation, 
this is solution:

```
    connect(&tcpClient, SIGNAL(disconnected()), SLOT(ReconnectToHost()));


    void ReconnectToHost(){tcpClient.connectToHost(theServerAddress, port);}
```

Comment: where is disconnected signal? Is it default or user defined ?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced such a problem.
What I did wrong is I tried to `QTcpSocket::connectToHost()` from withing a slot of my class, connected to `QTcpSocket::error()` signal. Finally I found a solution in this [post](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-18082?focusedCommentId=170619&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-170619).

If I am not mistaken, the problem is you can't reconnect from within this slot, because something important happens right after `QTcpSocket::error()` signal is emmited and flow of controll returns from your handler to the `QTcpSocket`'s method, which emitted this signal, or so you somehow break the socket's logic that way.

Not an elegant, but still one-line-of-code sollution is to call `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_socket, "connectToHost", Qt::QueuedConnection);`
once your `handle_socket_error()` slot has been called.

Beware if you call `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` on custom method, it must be registered as a slot.

UPD: Shame on me, but this issue is mentioned in Qt's `QAbstractSocket::error()` signal [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#error-1).

Answer (score 0):

socket.h:

```
    private slots:
    void reConnectServer(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error);
    private:
    QTcpSocket *mSocket;
    QString mHostname;
    int mPort;
```

socket.cpp:

```
    connect(&mSocket,&QTcpSocket::errorOccurred,this,&WorkerClient::reConnectServer);
    void Socket::reConnectServer(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)
    {
    qDebug()<<error;//e.g.,QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError
    if(!mSocket.waitForConnected(10000)){
    mSocket.connectToHost(mHostname,mPort);
    }
    }
```

Don't forget to add this in main.cpp:

```
    qRegisterMetaType<QAbstractSocket::SocketError>();
```

enum QAbstractSocket::SocketError:

This enum describes the socket errors that can occur.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketError-enum

Answer (score 0):

I use a timer to solve this problem and it works well so far.

```
QTcpSocket _client;
QTimer _timer;

//when server off, try to connect periodically
connect(&_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [&]{_client.connectToHost(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"),7920);});
_timer.setInterval(5000);
_timer.start();

//when connected, stop trying
connect(&_client, &QTcpSocket::connected, this, [&]{
    ((QTcpSocket *)QObject::sender())->write("connected");
    _timer.stop();
});

//when disconnected, try again
connect(&_client, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, [&]{_timer.start();});
```